# Windows Application ,vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows

I have a requirement where i need to have a menu strip control,if i click any, it should load the specific form with master form as background. Am new to window forms my question may appear silly. pleaes post your comments as son as possible , thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know how to open a form via code ??

Comment: In menustrip item click event write `With frmChildForm ' child form
            .MdiParent = Me ' using me becuase my menustrip control is in this form itself
            .Show()
            .Focus()
 End With`

Comment: If you are new to programming windows forms applications, I recommend getting a book and/or going through the MSDN guides:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6a6etxs.aspx